Is NTFS drive causing Ubuntu 24.04 to hang sometimes?
Ubuntu 24.04 running on my custom built PC hangs sometimes (intermittently) without any logs. Unfortunately, when it freezes, the keyboard and mouse become unresponsive, requiring a forceful power off. Here is the PC configuration:



Name
Description




CPU
Intel Core i9-13900K


GPU
MSI GeForce RTX 3090 VENTUS 3X 24G


RAM
Corsair DDR5-5600MHz 64GB (2 x 32GB)


SSD
CORSAIR MP600 PRO Low Profile Series 500 GB


HDD
Seagate BarraCuda 7200rpm 3.5" 2TB


Motherboard
ASUS PRIME Z790-P-CSM


SMPS
Corsair RM1000x Power Supply 1000W


Cooling
Cooler Master MasterLiquid ML240L V2 ARGB


Monitor
LG 27UL500-W Monitor Display, 27 inches, 4K



I could not SSH and Ping it when it hung. At that moment, a 2TB external disk (NTFS) was connected while I was transferring data from it. Is the NTFS drive causing Ubuntu 24.04 to hang sometimes?
Below is the OS information:
ravi@asus:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

ravi@asus:~$ uname -a
Linux asus 6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Apr 20 00:40:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ravi@asus:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ravi@asus:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

After forcefully rebooting the system, I collected the journalctl -b -1 log. This file is really long, so I split it into two and uploaded these parts to Pastebin in the following locations:

(part 1 of 2) journalctl -b -1.log
(part 2 of 2) journalctl -b -1.log

Here are some of the suspicious logs captured from the above files:

$ cat "journalctl -b -1.log" | grep -i ntfs
May 22 21:06:40 asus kernel: ntfs3: Max link count 4000
May 22 21:06:40 asus kernel: ntfs3: Enabled Linux POSIX ACLs support
May 22 21:06:40 asus kernel: ntfs3: Read-only LZX/Xpress compression included
May 22 21:07:33 asus kernel: ntfs3: sdb1: ino=24, Correct links count -> 1.
May 22 21:08:23 asus kernel: ntfs3: nvme0n1p3: ino=19340, Correct links count -> 1.
May 22 21:09:14 asus kernel: ntfs3: 13 callbacks suppressed
May 22 21:09:14 asus kernel: ntfs3: sdb1: ino=7c336, Correct links count -> 1.
May 22 21:09:19 asus kernel: ntfs3: 12841 callbacks suppressed
May 22 21:09:19 asus kernel: ntfs3: sdb1: ino=821f5, Correct links count -> 1.
May 22 21:09:24 asus kernel: ntfs3: 1326 callbacks suppressed
May 22 21:09:24 asus kernel: ntfs3: sdb1: ino=30, Correct links count -> 1.
May 22 21:09:24 asus kernel: ntfs3: 1326 callbacks suppressed
May 22 21:09:24 asus kernel: ntfs3: sdb1: ino=30, Correct links count -> 1.
May 22 21:12:05 asus kernel: ntfs3: 179 callbacks suppressed
May 22 21:12:05 asus kernel: ntfs3: sdb1: ino=ae497, Correct links count -> 1.
May 22 21:12:11 asus kernel: ntfs3: 1 callbacks suppressed
May 22 21:12:11 asus kernel: ntfs3: sdb1: ino=7c2c0, Correct links count -> 1.
May 22 21:12:20 asus kernel: ntfs3: 384 callbacks suppressed
May 22 21:12:20 asus kernel: ntfs3: sdb1: ino=57bad, Correct links count -> 1.


$ cat "journalctl -b -1.log" | grep -i error
May 22 20:15:29 asus kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
May 22 20:15:31 asus kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dsfield-184)
May 22 20:15:31 asus kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20230628/dswload2-477)
May 22 20:15:31 asus kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20230628/psparse-529)
May 22 20:15:31 asus systemd[1]: Started apport-autoreport.path - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch).
May 22 20:15:31 asus systemd[1]: Started apport-autoreport.timer - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (timer based).
May 22 20:15:31 asus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1686]:         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
May 22 20:15:32 asus wireplumber[1677]: Failed to get percentage from UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner
May 22 20:15:33 asus /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1822]: Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
May 22 20:15:33 asus gnome-session[1832]: gnome-session-binary[1832]: WARNING: Could not check if unit gnome-session-x11@gnome-login.target is active: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.systemd1: Process org.freedesktop.s>
May 22 20:15:33 asus gnome-session-binary[1832]: WARNING: Could not check if unit gnome-session-x11@gnome-login.target is active: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.systemd1: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with s>
May 22 20:15:34 asus gnome-shell[1851]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
May 22 20:15:37 asus gsd-sharing[1924]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
May 22 20:15:38 asus pipewire[2251]: mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.jackaudio.service was not provided by any .service files
May 22 20:15:41 asus gnome-session[2615]: gnome-session-binary[2615]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2630: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Failed to set unit properties: No such >
May 22 20:15:41 asus gnome-session-binary[2615]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2630: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Failed to set unit properties: No such process
May 22 20:15:41 asus gnome-session[2615]: gnome-session-binary[2615]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2646: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Failed to set unit properties: No such >
May 22 20:15:41 asus gnome-session-binary[2615]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2646: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Failed to set unit properties: No such process
May 22 20:15:41 asus gnome-session[2615]: gnome-session-binary[2615]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2916: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Failed to set unit properties: No such >
May 22 20:15:41 asus gnome-session-binary[2615]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Could not create transient scope for PID 2916: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnixProcessIdUnknown: Failed to set unit properties: No such process
May 22 20:15:42 asus gsd-sharing[1924]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing: The connection is closed
May 22 20:15:42 asus gsd-rfkill[1933]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill: The connection is closed
May 22 20:15:42 asus gsd-smartcard[1935]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard: The connection is closed
May 22 20:15:42 asus gsd-datetime[1941]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime: The connection is closed
May 22 20:15:42 asus gsd-a11y-settin[1979]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings: The connection is closed
May 22 20:15:42 asus gsd-screensaver[1961]: Error releasing name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver: The connection is closed
May 22 20:15:42 asus gsd-housekeepin[1988]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping: The connection is closed
May 22 20:15:42 asus gsd-sound[1973]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound: The connection is closed
May 22 20:15:42 asus kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
May 22 20:15:57 asus tracker-miner-fs-3[3437]: (tracker-extract-3:3437): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 20:15:57.102: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
May 22 20:57:18 asus google-chrome.desktop[3800]: [3793:3793:0522/205718.327248:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error>
May 22 20:57:26 asus google-chrome.desktop[3800]: [3840:3846:0522/205726.946191:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.fpapi.io., errorcode: -105
May 22 20:57:26 asus google-chrome.desktop[3800]: [3840:3846:0522/205726.949657:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.fpapi.io., errorcode: -105
May 22 20:57:26 asus google-chrome.desktop[3800]: [3840:3846:0522/205726.951177:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
May 22 20:57:32 asus google-chrome.desktop[3800]: [3793:3793:0522/205732.553229:ERROR:extension_registrar.cc(539)] Failed to unregister service worker for extension mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab
May 22 20:59:03 asus tracker-miner-fs-3[4657]: (tracker-extract-3:4657): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 20:59:03.742: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
May 22 20:59:10 asus gvfsd-network[4669]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: Failed to spawn the underlying wsdd daemon.
May 22 20:59:10 asus gvfsd-network[4669]: Couldn't create directory monitor on wsdd:///. Error: Automount failed: mountpoint for org.gtk.vfs.mountpoint_wsdd already running
May 22 21:10:40 asus tracker-miner-fs-3[6349]: (tracker-extract-3:6349): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 21:10:40.525: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
May 22 21:10:40 asus tracker-miner-fs-3[6349]: (tracker-extract-3:6349): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 21:10:40.525: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
May 22 21:15:29 asus systemd[1]: Starting apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
May 22 21:15:29 asus whoopsie-upload-all[6547]: ERROR: whoopsie.path is not enabled
May 22 21:15:29 asus systemd[1]: Failed to start apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.



What causes Ubuntu to freeze? Could my NTFS drive be the cause?

I'm thinking that the cause here could be glib via tracker-miner-fs-3.  See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/localsearch/-/issues/315. Ubuntu 24.04 is shipping with 2.80.0-1build1 but there is an upstream bug fix for 2.80.2.
This is also impacting snapd, preventing snap apps from launching with telltale syslog errors of:
tracker-miner-fs-3[37792]: (tracker-extract-3:37792): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 13:04:10.468: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)

You can try removing the tracker db and rebooting:
rm -rf ~/.cache/tracker*


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
